# show less or show more in javaScript html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code like this. I want to show maxlength 100 but when I click button I want to see all text. When I click button again I want to show length is going to be 100 again.
I didn't do it. Can you help me ?
Sorry for my English

```js
function MyButton () {
                    var x = document.getElementById("p1").maxLength = 300;
                    document.querySelector('.p1').innerText = x;
                    $("#More").css("display", "none")
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="p1" >
    Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined 
    </span>
 

    <button onclick="MyButton()" id="More">..Show More</button>
```

Comment: You have some errors in your js code, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little trick like this where you assign the full text content to a dataset attribute at page load but display the short version on the page.
When the button is clicked, assign the short text content to another dataset attribute and display the full text. This process then repeats to hide the full text when the button is clicked again.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.More').forEach(bttn=>{
  bttn.dataset.state=0;
  bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    let span=this.previousElementSibling;
        span.dataset.tmp=span.textContent;
        span.textContent=span.dataset.content;
        span.dataset.content=span.dataset.tmp;

        this.innerHTML=this.dataset.state==1 ? 'Show More...' : 'Show Less...';
        this.dataset.state=1-this.dataset.state;
  })
});

document.querySelectorAll('span.p1').forEach(span=>{
  span.dataset.content=span.textContent;
  span.textContent=span.textContent.substr(0,100) + '...';
})
```

```css
.p1{margin:1rem;display:block;}
```

```html
<span class="p1" >
  Breaking India: Western Interventions in Dravidian and Dalit Faultlines is a book written by Rajiv   Malhotra and Aravindan Neelakandan which argues that India's integrity is being undermined 
</span>
<button class="More">..Show More</button>


<span class="p1" >
  I hate yogurt. It's just stuff with bits in. You hit me with a cricket bat. All I've got to do is pass as an ordinary human being. Simple. What could possibly go wrong? I'm the Doctor, I'm worse than everyone's aunt. *catches himself* And that is not how I'm introducing myself.

  All I've got to do is pass as an ordinary human being. Simple. What could possibly go wrong? The way I see it, every life is a pile of good things and bad things.…hey.…the good things don't always soften the bad things; but vice-versa the bad things don't necessarily spoil the good things and make them unimportant.
</span>
<button class="More">..Show More</button>

<span class="p1" >
  Saving the world with meals on wheels. Saving the world with meals on wheels. It's art! A statement on modern society, 'Oh Ain't Modern Society Awful?'! I'm nobody's taxi service; I'm not gonna be there to catch you every time you feel like jumping out of a spaceship.

  You hit me with a cricket bat. You've swallowed a planet! You know how I sometimes have really brilliant ideas? Heh-haa! Super squeaky bum time! Aw, you're all Mr. Grumpy Face today.
</span>
<button class="More">..Show More</button>

<span class="p1" >
  Aw, you're all Mr. Grumpy Face today. I am the last of my species, and I know how that weighs on the heart so don't lie to me! All I've got to do is pass as an ordinary human being. Simple. What could possibly go wrong?

  You hit me with a cricket bat. No, I'll fix it. I'm good at fixing rot. Call me the Rotmeister. No, I'm the Doctor. Don't call me the Rotmeister. Stop talking, brain thinking. Hush. I am the last of my species, and I know how that weighs on the heart so don't lie to me!
</span>
<button class="More">..Show More</button>
```